# StreamingKit seekToTime method Not working

Tags: ios, seekbar

Here is my code. I am using `UISlider` as a seekbar, so when `UISlider` value is changed `- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender` is called.

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
[audioplayer seekToTime:_seekbar.value];
}
```

but `seekToTime` method is not firing. 
I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: is sliderValueChanged called ?

Comment: yap. but seekToTime method is not calling. :(

Comment: Is `audioplayer` nil?

Comment: yes, audioplayer showing nil, what I can I do now? @Larme

Comment: It depends. Where is it allocated? How is it defined? With just that bit of code that you showed, we can't guess what's wrong.

Comment: I have allocate audioplayer in ViewDidLoad().

Comment: are you playing the file from url ??

Comment: @zahidhasan: If you don't post the code, we can't guess what's wrong. We have found that `audioplayer` is `nil`, but that's all we can do with that little piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

int32_t timeScale = self.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;

[self.audioPlayer seekToTime: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(sender.value, timeScale)
             toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero
              toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero
           completionHandler: ^(BOOL finished) {
               [self.audioPlayer play];
           }];
}
```

Comment: I have already check that value is changing or not using NSLOG("").

No. Not working. Btw thank you. :) @Jenny Jose

Comment: try to add this method in - (IBAction)progressBarDraggindStop:(id)sender {
}